# Iphone4s calendar events gone

Tags: iphone

The events I have entered are gone. I can not enter them. The + is not working. Facebook birthdays are still there.  Also all my list are gone.

Comment: There are two problems you might want to separate. 1) Are your events really gone? If so, restore from a backup and/or check online with your calendar service if you have set up a calendar service. [and we can't really guess which of these is your best plan since we don't know enough about your setup before the problem arose]. 2) Troubleshooting adding new events once you've resolved the missing events issue or decided to start fresh with a new calendar.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, contacts and calendars "disappear" from the iPhone due to incorrect sync settings. On your iPhone, navigate to Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars and make sure to enable Calendar sync for each of your listed accounts.